# Trigger that selects only the new updates / affected rows

Tags: sql, triggers

I am a total noob to SQL, maybye my problem can seem basic.

I have a table, dbo.Sensors, that collects data from sensors, and i have to send this data to a broker with python. I can send the whole table, but now I would like to send only the new updates.

To do that, I made a trigger IF UPDATE, but I can't find how to select only the last lines added to the sensors table, and what to do with it (put it in a temporary table and send this table to the borker with python ? use the inserted table ?).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwjiB.png)

Is my first idea good, and how can I do the rest ?
Can you help me please ?

Comment: You have misunderstood the purpose of triggers. Your table probably has a `date` column typically called `CreateDate` or something similar, you just need a query to select the rows after a point -in-time - whatever "new" implies.

Comment: Really ?  I would like to select the last update as soon as it is written in the table - and that is automatically done by the sensors.

Comment: I have a TimeStamp column yes, I can maybye select the last date ? Thank you @Stu